# Custom handling Future failures in Akka Streams Flow

Tags: stream, akka, future

I try to connect multiple Flows in Akka Streams and handle their errors in different ways depending on the Flow. It can be accomplished using sth like that:

```
Flow[String, Either[ProcessingError, String], NotUsed]
```

And then divert response to error handler based on Either value.

My problem is, that some Flows return Future[String] instead of String and I don't know how to evaluate it to be able to catch error after each Flow and handle it in custom way.

Comment: It is very rare to have Flow[String, Future[String], NotUsed]. What is the use case?

Comment: It is possible, for example when making a query to the database, db returns Future[Entity]. I figured using mapAsync handles futures, but I an not sure if it's the most elegant way.

Comment: Yes, with akka streams, people normally do mapAsync or mapAsyncUnordered to handle future, not sure if that's elegant but that's a very common practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn the `Future` into an `Either` without failing the stream, you can use

```
.mapAsync(1){ e => 
  val f: Future[T] = ...
  f.transformWith(_.toEither)
}
```

`mapAsync` and `mapAsyncUnordered` are the idiomatic ways to evaluate futures in Akka Streams. Be aware that a failing future in those will fail the stream, to handle errors in-stream, you need to react "immediately" on the future to convert it into `Try` or `Either`.